# Change variable based on value of 'jQuery UI Slider'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update a variable based on the value of a jQuery UI Slider, which is then used within a function but I can't get it to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.drag').draggable();
    $("#hue").slider({
        min: -180,
        max: 180,
        value: 150,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#slideResult").text(ui.value);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $("#slideResultSecret").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    var hueValue = document.getElementById("slideResultSecret").value;
    $("#slideResult").text("null!");
});

$(window).load(function() {
    $('.window img').pixastic("hsl", {hue: hueValue, rect:{left:115,top:115,width:490,height:692}});
});
```

Does that make sense? It's hard to explain it when you don't fully understand it yourself.

Comment: `hueValue` is undefined inside `.pixastic()`.

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle? on the "change" event couldnt you just set your variable in there to whatever ui.value is??

Comment: Got it. It was enough to define the variable inside the change event like you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to define the variable inside the `change` event, like so:

```
change: function(event, ui) {
    hueResult = $("#hue").slider("value");
}
```